# OpenEdx Devstack Installation failing

Tags: openedx

I'm trying to install OpenEdx Devstack following the instruction mentioned here http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/devstack/install_devstack.html and `OPENEDX_RELEASE="open-release/eucalyptus.3"`

I'm facing below issue

TASK: [elasticsearch | Install Elasticsearch repo key] ************************

==> default: failed: [localhost] => {"cmd": "apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 36095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
==> default: stderr: gpg: requesting key D88E42B4 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net

==> default: gpg: keyserver timed out

==> default: gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

==> default: stdout: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.y5UWlpBXXc --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 36095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4

==> default: msg: gpg: requesting key D88E42B4 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net

==> default: gpg: keyserver timed out

==> default: gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

==> default:

==> default: FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

I'm behind a corporate firewall. Any help in resolving this error is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a problem due to the internet connection of **ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net**, try re-running

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. Force to use port 80.

Edit

```
apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 36095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4
```

to

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv 36095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4
```